# What does 0D mean in assembly 89 0D 0B00A85E - mov [5EA8000B],ecx

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86

i'm new to assembly and i would like to know what 0D stands for in:

```
89 0D 0B00A85E - mov [5EA8000B],ecx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `89 0D 0B00A85E` is the hex representation of the machine code for `mov [5EA8000B], ecx`.

[The `89` encodes the `mov r/m16/32, r16/32` instruction](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x89). The byte that follows is known as a "32-bit ModR/M Byte", and encodes the arguments to `mov`. The meaning can be seen [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#modrm_byte_32):

- the first argument is `disp32` (the immediate value of which -- `0B00A85E` -- follows the `0D`);
- the second argument is `ecx` (see the `r32(/r)` row at the top).